# I accidently locked some packages in synaptic, how can I undo these?

Tags: package-management, synaptic

If possible I would like to list them first and select which one to remove **OR** remove them all. Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command in a terminal:

```
grep ^Package: /var/lib/synaptic/preferences
```

To remove a lock, edit the file with an editor and remove the whole part. For example if `xterm` should be unlocked, remove those 3 lines in the file

```
Package: pdfsam
Pin: version 1.1.4-1
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Comment: It does working but how can I remove the locked?

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad If this shows you what packages are locked, can you not just load up Synaptic and unlock them?

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad see my edit

Comment: @Oli as it weird as it seem but **primus** package that listed by using command is not found in synaptic, but I remembered that I locked them previously, cause it make my graphic card break usually from upgrade, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Search through **Status>Pinned** as following in Synaptic:

[image]

And **remove** check-mark from **Package>Lock Version** as following:

[image: screen2]

Comment: @ Pandya huh, I didn't see it coming, that was easy... but it didn't list all package that was locked, as I used @chaos command I still got packages that locked, thanks anyway.

Comment: as I said before in my comment, that **primus** package that listed by using command is not found in synaptic. Your answer is correct but not quite precisely what I want. It's already solved, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad : Ok.